# How many rounds were played given...

Tags: probability

Vanessa and Mark play a game. They say they would play for at most 8 games, but maybe fewer. You saw Vanessa win 2 games (need not be consecutive). Later that day, Will tells you that the probability that you saw Vanessa win 2 gamesis exactly 1/2 given that you saw only two rounds total. How many games were played, and how many of them did each of them win?
I'm stumped on where to begin - help?

Comment: I would just try some values, e.g. Vanessa won 2 out of 3, or 2 out of 4, or 3 out of 4, etc. and see what happens. For example, take 2 out of 3. Then the chances of seeing Vanessa win 2 out of 2 is 2/3 * 1/2 = 1/3.  OK, not good. Try 2 out of 4: then it is 1/2 * 1/3 ... certainly not good. 3 out of 4?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $K$ rounds where played, and that Vanessa won $W$ of them.

What is the probability that you selected two rounds in which Vanessa won?

The probability is $\frac{W}{K}\frac{W-1}{K-1}=\frac{W(W-1)}{K(K-1)}$.

Therefore we must have $2W(W-1)=K(K-1)$.

This implies that $K$ or $K-1$ must be a multiple of $4$. Therefore $K=4,5,8$.

If $K=4$ then $W(W-1)=6$, so $W=3$.

If $K=5$ then $W(W-1)=10$, which is impossible.

If $K=8$ then $W(W-1)=28$, which is impossible.

We conclude $4$ games where played and Vanessa won $3$ of them.

Comment: Can you explain how you get to $\frac{W}{K} \frac{W-1}{K-1}$ ?

Comment: the probability the first round chosen it one in which Vanessa wins is $\frac{W}{K}$ since there are $W$ rounds in which Vanessa won and $K$ rounds total. the probability Vanessa wins the second round is $\frac{W-1}{K-1}$ since now only $W-1$ rounds remain in which Vanessa won out of the $K-1$ remaining rounds.